# How to display PHP variables in a proper HTML table

Tags: php, html, mybb

**Hey guys its my first question here I think.**

So I'm using MyBB Forum software.

I have a PHP code that fetches some data from a database no issues in there its working properly.

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM housing");
while($result = $db->fetch_array($query))
{    
    $housingvar .= "<td>". $result['username']. "</td>";
    $price .= "<td>". $result['Price']. "</td>";
    $city .= "<td>". $result['City']. "</td>";
    $tax .= "<td>". $result['Tax']. "</td>"; 
    $adrz .= "<td>". $result['Adress']. "</td>";
}
```

This is the code. I'm using. These variables are then plugged in an HTML table on the forum but everything is in the same column and I dont know how to make a new row for every data. I'm sure this is possible but dont know how.

I cant use echo in my PHP code either. Since I'm using these variables in a pure HTML template.

```
<tr>
    {$housingvar}
         {$price} 
          {$city}
            {$adrz}
            {$tax}
    </tr>
```

Comment: Does your templating software provide its own looping mechanism? You can't collect each row's value into a single variable, because they have to be split onto different rows of the table.

Comment: I'm not really sure about that..

Comment: If it doesn't, then there doesn't seem to be a way to do what you want. If the variables all have to be between a single `<tr>` and `</tr>`, there's no way to get multiple rows. Surely the designers of your template provided a way to generate tables of data from PHP arrays.

Comment: @Barmar How would you normally loop in PHP. Can you give me a small example if you don't mind?

Comment: The answers show the normal way to loop over the results of a query. But they won't work for the way you're templating this.

Comment: `.echo "<table>";

while($result = $db->fetch_array($query))
{
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $result['username'] . "</td>"; 
  echo "<td>" . $result['Price']. "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $result['City']. "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $result['Tax']. "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $result['Adress']. "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";`

I have used this code and now new rows are working however.. The echo is causing problems.. There are 2 tables on my page now, One from the HTML and one due to ECHO. How do I remove the echo one?

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

`<tr>` for table row and `<td>` for table data.
However you have to wrap your while statement with table tag:

```
$output = "";
$output .= "<table>";
while ($result = $db->fetch_array($query)) {
     // Starting a new table row
     $output .= "<tr>";
        $output .= "<td>".htmlentities($result['username']). "</td>";
        /* Append the rest of the fields */
     // End of row
     $output .= "</tr>";
}
$output .= "</table>";
{ $output }
```

Comment: This answer doesn't escape any of the data being output, and can lead to invalid HTML and security issues.  Use `htmlspecialchars()` or similar.

Comment: Hey so the thing is I cant use PHP on my HTML file. So I did this but what variable would I call from my HTML file exactly? @AbdAlrahmanHashem

Comment: @Brad The concern was not about escaping, but I just edited it thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To create a new row in an HTML table, you use the `<tr>` tag. I would try the following:

```
echo "<tr>";
   $price = $result['Price'];
   echo "<td> $price </td>";
    //other code here
echo "</tr>";
```

Comment: I cant use echo. I'm using these variables directly on my templates which has a pure HTML structure.

 <tr>
  {$housingvar}
         {$price} 
          {$city}
   {$adrz}
   {$tax}
        </tr>